# jquery dialog box adjust height weight and change the title bar background and close button img

Tags: jquery, dialog, height

i am working with jquery dialog box... I dont want to use the way they use google api for background color theme, I want to use my own for ex: close button has to be in a circle with X, title bar's background should be set to #FFFFFF, and height and width of dialog box has to be adjusted to my data (not dynamically though), please guide me, so far I am able to popup the div in dialog box but the height and width can not be adjusted. can some one guide me a tutorial or tweaks...many thanks

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="JqueryLib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="application_1.css"></h:outputStylesheet>
<style type="text/css">


</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#viewDetails").click(function(){

$("#popup").dialog();



})    
});
</script>
</h:head>
<body>
<form id="Form1">
<h:outputText id= "viewDetails" value="View Details" outcome="#"/>
<div id="popup" class="popup" title="MyTitle" style="display: none">
This is my data table....where I can not adjust the data inside the dialog box...
</div>

</form>
</body>
</ui:composition>
```

I dont want to use google api which has themes for title bar. I want to customize css

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code. It didn't show up in the comment.

Comment: I am not able to add code for some reason...can u help me with that? do I hav to have 5 reputations?? when I add my code it says to long by 500 characters..

Comment: Edit your original post, not in a comment. The edit link is below the blue tags, under your post text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to customize your jQuery dialog box:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({position:['middle',60],  // set the position on the page to the middle and 60px down from the top margin
        open: function(event, ui) {  
        jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span style="float:right;"><img src="/EIWeb/images/Icons/x.png" /></span>');  // remove the titlebar background, remove the default button and replace with my own
    },  
        dialogClass: 'ui-widget-shadow',  // display a widget shadow
        modal: true,    // display the modal overlay
        autoOpen: false, // do not auto open
        width: '650px', // force set the width

        close: function(ev, ui) {$(this).close();}  // Set the dialog to close and remove upon clicking the "x" 
    });

    $( ".dialogOpener" ).click(function() { // Set a class to open the dialog
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
    $( ".btnDone" ).click(function(){ // Set a class to close the dialog
        $('.ui-dialog-content').dialog( "close" );
    });
});
```

What this says is that I want to remove the background titlebar shading (so there is none, just the title), I want to remove the default close buton and replace it with my own "x" image, invoke the ui-widget-shadow class, and set the width to 650px.

Also, this says that when the close "x" is clicked, it will close and remove the dialog.  I have also classed a button, "btnDone" to use as a closer within the dialog (e.g. 'cancel' button).

If this helps, please give me ups.